# R fitting an S-shaped or cumulative function to estimate values outside data range

Tags: r, cdf

I have some data points on % penetration of a product for a specific time window and i would like to estimate the "before and after" that time window using an S-shaped function that starts around %penetration=zero and ends around %penetration=1, so effectively like a cumulative distribution function.

Here's the data:

```
period<-seq(13,73,1)
value<-c(0.267, 0.292, 0.317, 0.342, 0.367, 0.394, 0.422, 0.450, 0.477, 0.492, 0.507, 0.522, 0.537, 0.562, 0.587, 0.612, 0.637, 0.645, 0.652, 0.660, 0.667, 0.675, 0.682, 0.690, 0.697, 0.704, 0.711, 0.718, 0.724, 0.729, 0.734, 0.739, 0.743, 0.748, 0.753, 0.757, 0.762, 0.766, 0.770, 0.774, 0.778, 0.782, 0.786, 0.790, 0.794, 0.797, 0.800, 0.803, 0.806, 0.809, 0.812, 0.814, 0.817, 0.820, 0.822, 0.824, 0.827, 0.829, 0.831, 0.834, 0.836)
```

So my time window goes from period=13 to period=73 and I would like to estimate values for periods 1 to 12 (starting close to value=zero) and periods 74 to 140 (ending close to value=1).
Any idea how i can do this...?
thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Below we show 4 variations and plot them so we can visually assess the fit.

**1) LL.4** We could try the LL.4 model of the drc package:

```
> library(drc)
> value.m1 <- drm(value ~ period, fct = LL.4())
>
> before <- predict(value.m1, data.frame(period = 1:12)); before
 [1] -0.021014377 -0.014620515 -0.003811402  0.011217655  0.030115032
 [6]  0.052416255  0.077583272  0.105041527  0.134213115  0.164544170
[11]  0.195525422  0.226705738
> after <- predict(value.m1, data.frame(period = 74:140)); after
 [1] 0.8295972 0.8309413 0.8322356 0.8334824 0.8346839 0.8358422 0.8369594
 [8] 0.8380374 0.8390778 0.8400824 0.8410528 0.8419904 0.8428968 0.8437731
[15] 0.8446209 0.8454411 0.8462350 0.8470037 0.8477483 0.8484696 0.8491687
[22] 0.8498463 0.8505035 0.8511409 0.8517594 0.8523597 0.8529424 0.8535083
[29] 0.8540579 0.8545920 0.8551109 0.8556154 0.8561059 0.8565830 0.8570470
[36] 0.8574986 0.8579380 0.8583658 0.8587823 0.8591880 0.8595831 0.8599681
[43] 0.8603433 0.8607090 0.8610656 0.8614132 0.8617523 0.8620831 0.8624058
[50] 0.8627207 0.8630281 0.8633282 0.8636213 0.8639074 0.8641869 0.8644600
[57] 0.8647268 0.8649875 0.8652424 0.8654915 0.8657351 0.8659733 0.8662063
[64] 0.8664342 0.8666572 0.8668754 0.8670889
> plot(value.m1, xlim = c(1, 140), ylim = 0:1, pch = 20)
```

The extrapolation going forward looks like it might be systematically too low and the `before` values go below zero but perhaps that is sufficient for your needs.

(continued after image)

[image: screenshot LL.4]

**2) MM.3** Visually, the `MM.3` model produces a better fit at the upper end but a bit worse at the lower end:

```
value.m2 <- drm(value ~ period, fct = MM.3())
plot(value.m2, xlim = c(1, 140), ylim = 0:1, pch = 20)
```

(continued after image)

[image: screenshot MM.3]

**3) Combined** One could pick up the best of both using the following (continuing on from the last plot):

```
value.pred1 <- predict(value.m1, data.frame(period = 1:140))
value.pred2 <- predict(value.m2, data.frame(period = 1:140))
value.pred12 <- c( head(value.pred1, 19), tail(value.pred2, -19) )
lines(1:140, value.pred12, col = "red")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot combined]

**4) Cumulative Scale**  If we fit on the cumulative scale LL.4 gives a visually pleasing plot:

```
DF <- data.frame(value.cum = cumsum(value), period)
fm <- drm(value.cum ~ period, data = DF, fct = LL.4())
plot(fm, xlim = c(1, 140), ylim = c(0, 100), pch = 20)
```

[image: cumulative fit screenshot]

*ADDED* `MM.3` model, combined model and cumulative model.

Comment: But in the long run is this "better" than my cheapo approach?  I fear beauty is in the eye of the OP :-)

Comment: that's absolutely fantastic, thank you so much!  i'd never come across the drc package before.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I plotted your dataset, and frankly do not recommend an "S" curve.   I would do a linear fit over `period < 30`  and a separate power fit, perhaps `y = k*sqrt(x)` to `period > 30` .

Be warned that extrapolation outside a dataset is always a risky move unless you have great faith that the data are based on the function (e.g. linear) you used to fit to the dataset.